# How do I mirror sub directory of a website with wget

Tags: linux, wget

I need to mirror the following URL:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100515230709/http://markowitzbocadentist.com/

But I need to mirror only files from this date '20100515230709' i have tried many `wget` options but they either grab index.html or files from other dates as well.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

From the wget manual (1.15):

> Actually, to download a single page and all its requisites (even if they exist on separate websites), and make sure the lot displays properly locally, this author likes to use a few options in addition to ‘-p’:
>
> wget -E -H -k -K -p url

Also, robots.txt may be blocking some content, so add -e robots=off

So you get:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off https://web.archive.org/web/20100515230709/http://markowitzbocadentist.com/
```

This gave me 38 files, all needed for that single page and no more.

If you want to get more than just that page, you need to download (parts of) snapshots from earlier days too. Because archive.org only fetches the *changed* pages, a *complete site* on a *specific date* almost always consists of pages that were captured on that date, but on older dates too. For example the link to "Procedures" refers to a copy made on 2010-10-21 at 08:29:33, which is earlier than the date you mentioned (2010-05-15 at 23:07:09).

So the actual answer to your question is: you can't mirror a *complete* snapshot of one date without at least downloading parts from another date's snapshot too.

Adding the -m (mirror option) fetches those pages too.

Comment: i need to download that whole website not just index.html and its all pages

Comment: To get all the pages, add the -m option. Now more versions of your site are retrieved, but that's because archive.org only fetches the **changed** pages. For example the link to "Procedures" refers to a copy made on 2010-10-21 at 08:29:33. So maybe the actual answer to your question is: you can't copy a **complete** snapshot of one date without at least downloading parts from another date's snapshot too. I'll add that to the answer.